# Return the lines which have no given symbol in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, readline

I want to print the lines from a website's content page which do not start with the symbol `"#"`.

```
def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

page_content = open('https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00000.md5')

line_num=0
page_content.each_line do |lines|
  line_num += 1
  if lines[0] == "#"
    lines.each_line do |line|
      if (line_num==1)
        puts line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Expected result:

```
2d75cc1bf8e57872781f9cd04a529256
00f538c3d410822e241486ca061a57ee
3f066dd1f1da052248aed5abc4a0c6a1
781770fda3bd3236d0ab8274577dddde
................................
```

It works when I try to print the lines that start with `"#"`:

```
lines[0] != "#"
```

But it does not work in the opposite way.

Comment: Contain or start with? Try `if  lines.include? "#"`

Comment: Edited, thank you. it starts with @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I prefer to do with the starting one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a mix of `reject` and `start_with?` :

```
require 'net/http'
def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

page_content = open('https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00000.md5')

puts page_content.each_line.reject{ |line| line.start_with?('#') }
```

It outputs :

```
2d75cc1bf8e57872781f9cd04a529256
00f538c3d410822e241486ca061a57ee
3f066dd1f1da052248aed5abc4a0c6a1
781770fda3bd3236d0ab8274577dddde
86b6c59aa48a69e16d3313d982791398
42914d6d213a20a2684064be5c80ffa9
10699ac57f1cf851ae144ebce42fa587
248338632580f9c018c4d8f8d9c6c408
999eb1840c209aa70a84c5cf64909e5f
12c4201fe1db96a1a1711790b52a3cf9
................................
```

If you just want the first line :

```
page_content.each_line.find{ |line| !line.start_with?('#') }
```

## Notes

```
page_content.each_line do |lines|
```

`lines` should be called `line`. It is just one line.

When you call

```
lines.each_line do |line|
```

You iterate over "each" line of just one line, so the loop isn't needed at all.

Your code could be :

```
require 'net/http'

def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

page_content = open('https://virusshare.com/hashes/VirusShare_00000.md5')

page_content.each_line do |line|
  puts line if line[0] != "#"
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have another question. How can i take the first line of the line does not start with "#"?. I'm using array now, but it's not a decent way to to. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I just wanna take this line only "2d75cc1bf8e57872781f9cd04a529256". it's the first line of the output.